# Linux - NodeJS, Express, PostgreSQL - ErrorHandler: password authentication failed for user "root"

Tags: javascript, postgresql, express, environment-variables

Edit -

Success! I should have `RTFM` it seems. Using the environmental variables seems to be required to be EXACT to the manual.

Fixed code:

```
# PostgreSQL Database Infomation
PGDATABASE_TEST = user_db
PGDATABASE = user_db
PGUSER = postgres
PGPASSWORD = password

# PostgreSQL Host and Port Infomation
PGHOST = localhost
PGPORT = 5432
```

--

I'm using `.env` variables to connect to a Postgres Database.

When submitting data via Postman to a Express API I receive an error stating the following:

```
            throw new ErrorHandler(error.statusCode, error.message)
                  ^

ErrorHandler: password authentication failed for user "tito"
    at UserService.createUserAccount (/home/tito/Documents/GitHub/***/server/services/user.service.js:11:19)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async createUserAccount (/home/tito/Documents/GitHub/***/server/controllers/user.controller.js:11:18) {
  status: 'error',
  statusCode: undefined
}
```

As you can see, its using my OS username rather than `.env` set one. When running node with `sudo` I get the auth error with `root`.

My `db.js`:

```
require("dotenv").config();
const { Pool } = require("pg");

// Check which Database to use. Live is safe.
const isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'PRODUCTION';
const database = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'TEST' ? process.env.PG_TEST_DATABASE : process.env.PG_DATABASE;

// Request to Database contructed
const connectionString = `postgresql://${process.env.PG_USER}:${process.env.PG_PASS}@${process.env.PG_HOST}:${process.env.PG_PORT}/${database}`;

// Setup Pool. 
const pool = new Pool ({
    connectionString: isProduction ? process.env.DATABASE_URL : connectionString,
    ssl: isProduction ? { rejectUnauthorized: false } : false
});

console.log(`Ready at : ${connectionString}`)

module.exports = {
    query: (text, params) => pool.query(text, params),
    end: () => pool.end()
}
```

My `.env`:

```
# Express API Port.
PORT = 5000

# Enviroment - TEST for local. PRODUCTION for live.
NODE_ENV = PRODUCTION

# PostgreSQL Database Infomation
PG_TEST_DATABASE = user_db
PG_DATABASE = user_db
PG_USER = postgres
PG_PASS = password

# PostgreSQL Host and Port Infomation
PG_HOST = localhost
PG_PORT = 5432
```

My `UserService`:

```
const {
    createUserAccount_DB
} = require("../db/user.db");
const { ErrorHandler } = require("../helpers/error")

class UserService {
    createUserAccount = async (user) => {
        try {
            return await createUserAccount_DB(user);
        } catch (error) {
            throw new ErrorHandler(error.statusCode, error.message)
        }
    }
}

module.exports = new UserService();
```

And my `createUserAccount`:

```
const userService = require("../services/user.service");
const { ErrorHandler } = require("../helpers/error");

const createUserAccount = async (req, res) => {

    console.log("Create Account API Triggered");

    const { user_name, user_pass, user_email } = req.body;
    // const hashedPassword = hashedPassword(password);
     
    const user = await userService.createUserAccount({
        user_name,
        user_pass,
        user_email
    });

    res.status(201).json({
        status: "success",
        user,
    })
};
```

Comment: Can you try removing the spaces in your `.env` file. Try and keep it compact... `PG_USER=postgres`

Comment: _`connectionString: isProduction ? process.env.DATABASE_URL : connectionString`_ <- don't see a `DATABASE_URL` property in your `.env` file 

Answer (score 0):

Success! I should have `RTFM` it seems. Using the environmental variables seems to be required to be EXACT to the manual.

Fixed code:

```
# PostgreSQL Database Infomation
PGDATABASE_TEST = user_db
PGDATABASE = user_db
PGUSER = postgres
PGPASSWORD = password

# PostgreSQL Host and Port Infomation
PGHOST = localhost
PGPORT = 5432
```